# I have an array but how do i now insert as csv values php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv

I have this from my print_r

```
Array
(
    [jform] => Array
        (
            [itinerary] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

I have some code and then this bit

```
    foreach($_POST as $value) {

    $extraDATA[] = $value; 

    }

    $extraDATA = implode(',',$extraDATA);


   $updatEntry="UPDATE #__tours SET itinerary='$extraDATA' WHERE id='$id'";
   $db->setQuery($updatEntry);
   $db->query();
```

I can not get that array to produce 1,2 so i can update the row.

Cheers in advance
Jonny

Comment: It really isn't a good idea to store comma-separated data in a database; far better to normalise your table structures

Comment: its a very simple field that will hold a bunch of numbers. I have no choice over the database structure unfortunately.

Comment: @MarkBaker i don't understand why you commented unless you were willing to help? you're obviously quite intelligent but unless you are willing to link me to more information or guide me through what you mean then its kind of pointless to my question. I just have a very simple question. It will work for what i need and is completely secure. Im just stumped because everything i have tried just returns the word array.

Comment: My comment was made to try and __help__ prevent you doing something you'll regret doing in the future, and included the keywords like "normalise" to allow you to do a simple google search.... I'm sorry I bothered now

Comment: @MarkBaker ok im sorry i commented back. I didnt me to guilt trip me. I am in no way as clued up as you and all i wanted was help with my question as i did not ask is there a better way to do this. Anyways enjoy your day/night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you wanna do something like:

```
$extraDATA = implode(',', $_POST['jform']['itinerary']);
```

Basically you wanna `implode()` the child-array that has no more children.

Comment: Im trying this but i think i did and it did not work.I will let you know shortly.

Comment: Could you post the result for `print_r($_POST)` if it doesn't work, I can't guess your form-structure :)

Comment: i have updated my question with the print_r($POST) and it is slightly different yes.

Comment: Changed my answer accordingly :)

Comment: That is immensely helpful. You have taught me something. I am very much a hobby coder and not after a noble prize by far lol. Thanks heaps mate :)